# Всплывающая подсказка

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.
Нужно сделать всплывающую подсказку над кнопками соцсетей такого вида [image]
 подскажите возможные варианты реализации. не код, а общий алгоритм, как это сделать.
html-код кнопок такой

```
<div class="b-socials">
                <a href="#" class="b-socials__link"><img src="images/icon_social-rss.png" alt=""></a>

                <a href="http://vk.com/larson_holz_it_ltd" class="b-socials__link"><img src="images/icon_social-vk.png" alt=""></a>

                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/LarsonHolz-It-Ltd/217822734979282" class="b-socials__link"><img src="images/icon_social-fb.png" alt=""></a>

                <a href="https://twitter.com/#!/Larson_Holz" class="b-socials__link"><img src="images/icon_social-t.png" alt=""></a>

                <a href="http://lh-broker.livejournal.com/" class="b-socials__link"><img src="images/icon_social-lj.png" alt=""></a>

                <a href="" class="b-socials__link"><img src="images/icon_social-photo.png" alt=""></a>

                <a href="" class="b-socials__link"><img src="images/icon_social-heart.png" alt=""></a>


            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для подсказки вам нужен один див с position: absolute. Пускай при наведении он добавляется в конец body. Получите координаты элемента, около которого нужна подсказка, относительно документа (offset().left/top на jQuery). Относительно этих значений задайте нужные координаты для подсказки.

Comment: да, я примерно так и делаю, вот код http://jsfiddle.net/YwU2S/2/ , только почему-то не срабатывает и вылезает ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' . В чем тут дело?

Comment: напишите:
$('.l-cnt__side').on('mouseenter mouseleave','.b-socials__link', function() { ... });

и еще у вас в html ошибка - лишняя одинарная ковычка.

Answer (score 0):

Постройте рамку, которая будет находиться около кнопки. Можно обойтись одной картинкой или [этим способом](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/kak-sdelat-slovesnyi-puzyr-na-css3-bez-kartinok)

Comment: нет, у меня есть фоновое изображение для всплывающей подсказки. я просто не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы она отображалась под нужной кнопкой.

Answer (score 0):

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

либо делай отдельный див на подсказку, спрячь его + показывай при наведении мышки, лови событие onmouseenter, onmouseleave и стать display: none

Comment: получается, если делать скрытые дивы, то их придется делать под каждой кнопкой? это-то как-то не хорошо. в нешний вид всплывающей подсказки в этом плагине редактируется? можно будет задать свой бэкграунд?

Comment: конечно можно, смотри css background. конечно под каждой (точнее не под, а где угодно). либо динамически генери. либо одну на все, либо рамку одну, текст разный и задавай относительные координаты. не вижу проблем тут больше

Comment: у тебя ошибка в  "});

</script>
});//]]>  

</script>" - это шо за фигня? глянь исходник

Comment: $('.l-cnt__side').on('mouseenter mouseleave','.b-roundBox .b-socials a.b-socials__link',function(e){ - тут что-то явно неправильно, т.к. алерт не срабатывает, сделай просто onmouseover и внуть через this элементы ищи

Comment: и потом, ты алгоритм спрашивал или полностью решение? если просто алгоритм, то тебе его сказали, а нюансы уже сам сможешь допилить, http://jsfiddle.net/YwU2S/17/

Comment: да нет, со скриптом всё нормально было, просто библиотека jQuery была старая подключена, 1.6.4, в ней метода on() не было, после подключения библиотеки 1.8.2 всё заработало.

Answer (score -1):

Не очень понимаю какого типа вы хотите всплывающую подсказку, если совсем простую, можно CSS и без jquery.
[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/GU8sf/)